# Template function messed up

Tags: c++, function, templates, typeid, typeinfo

so im having a bit of problem with my ResourceManager class for a game im working on with c++.
so i tried to make a template function out of my regular addImage function so it will add sounds too but i got some errors which i cant really handle can you guys help me? :D

.hpp

```
#ifndef RESOURCE_MANAGER_HPP
#define RESOURCE_MANAGER_HPP

#include "Image.cpp"
#include "SoundBuffer.cpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

typedef std::map<std::string, sz::Image*> ImagesContainer;
typedef std::map<std::string, sz::Image*>::iterator ImagesContainerIt;
typedef std::map<std::string, sz::SoundBuffer*> SoundsContainer;
typedef std::map<std::string, sz::SoundBuffer*>::iterator SoundsContainerIt;
typedef std::map<std::string, sf::Music*> MusicContainer;
typedef std::map<std::string, sf::Music*>::iterator MusicContainerIt;

namespace sz
{
        //      meanwhile this class is only for images, need to edit later for
        //      it to be also able to load sounds, etc...
        class ResourceManager{
                private:
                ResourceManager() {};
                ResourceManager(ResourceManager const&) {};
                static ResourceManager *rm;
                // add functions and variables here
                ImagesContainer imagesContainer;
                SoundsContainer soundsContainer;
                MusicContainer  musicContainer;
                template <class type>
                void AddNew(std::string imagePath);

                public:
                static ResourceManager *Instance();
                // add functions here
                template <class type>
                type *Get(std::string imagePath);
        };
}

#endif
```

.cpp

```
#include "ResourceManager.hpp"
#include <typeinfo>

namespace sz
{
        ResourceManager *ResourceManager::rm = NULL;  

        ResourceManager *ResourceManager::Instance()
        {
           if (!rm)
                  rm = new ResourceManager;

           return rm;
        }

        template <class type>
        void ResourceManager::AddNew(std::string filePath)
        {
                type *item = new type(filePath);
                if(typeid(type) == typeid(sz::Image))
                        imagesContainer[filePath] = item;
                else if(typeid(type) == typeid(sz::SoundBuffer))
                        soundsContainer[filePath] = item;
                else
                        return;
        }

        template <class type>
        type *ResourceManager::Get(std::string filePath)
        {
                if(typeid(type) == typeid(sz::Image))
                {
                        ImagesContainerIt it = imagesContainer.find(filePath);
                        if(it == imagesContainer.end())
                        {
                                AddNew<type>(filePath);
                        }
                        it = imagesContainer.find(filePath);
                        return it->second;
                }

                else if(typeid(type) == typeid(sz::SoundBuffer))
                {
                        SoundsContainerIt it = soundsContainer.find(filePath);
                        if(it == soundsContainer.end())
                        {
                                AddNew<type>(filePath);
                        }
                        it = soundsContainer.find(filePath);
                        return it->second;
                }

                else
                        return NULL;
        }
}
```

the errors @_@

```
g++ -Wall -c "Sprite.cpp" (in directory: /home/gannash/Desktop/Open Heroes/Engine)
In file included from Sprite.cpp:2:0:
ResourceManager.cpp: In member function ‘type* sz::ResourceManager::Get(std::string) [with type = sz::Image, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’:
Sprite.cpp:10:65:   instantiated from here
ResourceManager.cpp:50:15: error: cannot convert ‘sz::SoundBuffer*’ to ‘sz::Image*’ in return
ResourceManager.cpp: In member function ‘void sz::ResourceManager::AddNew(std::string) [with type = sz::Image, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’:
ResourceManager.cpp:36:5:   instantiated from ‘type* sz::ResourceManager::Get(std::string) [with type = sz::Image, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’
Sprite.cpp:10:65:   instantiated from here
ResourceManager.cpp:23:4: error: cannot convert ‘sz::Image*’ to ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, sz::SoundBuffer*>::mapped_type {aka sz::SoundBuffer*}’ in assignment
ResourceManager.cpp: In member function ‘type* sz::ResourceManager::Get(std::string) [with type = sz::Image, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’:
ResourceManager.cpp:55:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: im pretty noob in all this so thanks for letting me know ill do my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is my idea after having a look at the code and error messages.

You cannot return Image and Sound from the same function like that. They are individual types. And you have to specify what type is going to be returned. When you put the if/else in your template it still will check to see if it can return all those types, and that will fail.

You have to return a BaseClass*(or whatever you want to call it) that both Image and Sound inherits from.

Comment: oh thanks man i understand i have to make something polyphormic for this. thanks very much!

Comment: -1, wrong. You cannot return `Image` and `Sound` from one function, that's true. However, `Get<Image>` and `Get<Sound>` are two functions so the logic behind this answer is flawed. The real problem is that `Get<Image>` can't return a `Sound` and vice versa. This isn't a big problem, you solve it by picking the right `Container` given `type`. This is a compile-time choice so nothing polymorphic is needed.

Comment: @MSalters No I belive that you are wrong. Look at the code again please. According to the code both an Image and Sound is returned from this function and that will not work because it is in the same function. The code is iterating through all Sounds and Images in the same template function. The function can only return one type but it tries to return both. That's why it fails.

Comment: @mantler: `Get` is not a function, but a function template. In the template, the intended goal is to iterate through one of the two containers depending on `type` - i.e. the two functions produced by template instantiation each should iterate through one container. It fails because the container selection can't be done with `if(typeid(type) == typeid(sz::Image))`

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I agree with you that my logic was flawed. I only thought of the issue that all of the function templates had if/else statements trying to return several types. A mix of intents.

Answer (score 0):

The templated function have to be completely defined for the compiler to able to use them. That means you have to move the body of those function from the source file to the header file.

**Edit:**

You have to check the how you use the template class. See for example this error message:

> ResourceManager.cpp:50:15: error: cannot convert ‘sz::SoundBuffer*’ to ‘sz::Image*’ in return

Unless `sz::SoundBuffer` inherits from `sz::Image` you have a mismatch between types.

Comment: sorry man didnt work, i moved all of the code to the header file but the errors seem to still appear :(

Answer (score 0):

"Compile-time if" is done via template partial specialization. But here it's not even needed:

```
template<typename type> struct Container {
  static std::map<std::string, type*> container;
};
std::map<std::string, sz::Image*>& ImagesContainer = Container<sz::Image>::container;
// etc...
template <class type>
void ResourceManager::AddNew(std::string filePath)
{
  type *item = new type(filePath);
  Container<type>::container[filePath] = item;
}
```

Comment: well i did not know that this is possible, but thank you mate i will sure try it out!